# Show <div> on <li> click

Tags: javascript, html, angular.js

Simple task, I am just trying to have the data that correlates to a menu item hidden until it is clicked. However, I feel like this can be optimized. There are 2 `ng-repeat`s, which is a little redundant but I can't think of another way to do it. What do you think?

See [JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/josueespinosa/qAFRA/)

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

    function($scope) {
        $scope.boxes = [{
            link: 'link1',
            content: 'content1'
        }, {
            link: 'link2',
            content: 'content2'
        }];

        $scope.current = {
            item: $scope.boxes[0]
        };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in boxes" ng-click="current.item = x">{{x.link}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-repeat="x in boxes" ng-show="x == current.item">{{x.content}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made an alternate with only one repeat, though I don't know if it's any better. I'll leave that to you to decide. http://jsfiddle.net/qAFRA/2/

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

    function($scope) {
        $scope.boxes = [{
            link: 'link1',
            content: 'content1'
        }, {
            link: 'link2',
            content: 'content2'
        }, {
            link: 'link3',
            content: 'content3'
        }, {
            link: 'link4',
            content: 'content4'
        }, {
            link: 'link5',
            content: 'content5'
        }, {
            link: 'link6',
            content: 'content6'
        }];

        $scope.selected = {
            id : 0
        };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(id, box) in boxes" ng-click="selected.id = id">{{box.link}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div>{{boxes[selected.id].content}}</div>
</div>
```